# Passing selected value of dropdownlist to a controller after postback

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2, pagedlist

How to pass the selected value of a drop down list from view to controller after postback. As i'm new to the MVC architecture any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
I need to filter data based on the values of dropdown list. But when i move to the next page of pagedlist then all my dropdown list's value is set to default value.

Controller

```
    public ActionResult ViewDataOfDatabase(string sortorder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page,FormCollection collection) 
     {
         CCIRepository _repository = CCIRepository.CreateRepository();
         AirtelManagementModel _Airtelmodel = new AirtelManagementModel();
         IEnumerable<CityListClass> CityList = _repository.GetCities();
         IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CityNames = from c in CityList
                                                     select new SelectListItem()
                                                     {
                                                         Value = c.CityName.ToString(),
                                                         Text = c.CityName.ToString(),
                                                         Selected = c.CityName == Request["CityNames"],
                                                     };
         ViewBag.CityList = CityNames;
         IEnumerable<clsYearOfDate> SelectList = GetYears();
         //IEnumerable<MonthListClass> SelectMonthList = GetMonths(YearId);
         IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Yearitems = (from v in SelectList
                                             select new SelectListItem()
                                             {
                                                 Value = v.YearSelectedId.ToString(),
                                                 Text = v.YearOfDate.ToString(),
                                                 Selected = v.YearOfDate == Request["Yearitems"],
                                             });

         ViewBag.SelectList = Yearitems;
         int DateId=0;
         string CityName = string.Empty; 
         try 
         { 

                int SelectedYear = Convert.ToInt16(collection["Yearitems"].ToString());
                int SelectedMonth = Convert.ToInt16(collection["MonthItems"].ToString());
                CityName = collection["CityNames"].ToString();
                DateId = _repository.GetImportDateId(SelectedYear, SelectedMonth);
                ViewBag.SelectedYear = SelectedYear;
                ViewBag.SelectedMonth = SelectedMonth;
                ViewBag.SelectedCity = CityName;

         }
         catch(NullReferenceException Ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(Ex);
         }
         //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthItems = (from m in SelectMonthList
         //                                          select new SelectListItem()
         //                                          {
         //                                              Value = m.MonthSelectedId.ToString(),
         //                                              Text = m.MonthName,


         //                                          });
         //ViewBag.SelectMonthList = MonthItems;
         IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthItems = Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>();
         ViewBag.SelectMonthList = MonthItems;
        List<AirtelManagementModel> list = ViewDetails();
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortorder;

        ViewBag.PhoneSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortorder) ? "Phone_desc" : "";
        if (searchString != null )
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            searchString = currentFilter;
        }
        //if(searchString!=null)
        //{

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
            var airteldetails = from _model in list
                                select _model;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) && DateId!=0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(CityName))
            {
                airteldetails = _repository.FilterAirtelDetails(searchString, DateId, CityName);
                int PageSize = 5;
                int PageNumber = (page ?? 1);
                return View(airteldetails.ToPagedList(PageNumber, PageSize));
            }
            //airteldetails=airteldetails.OrderByDescending(A=>A.AirtelNumber);
            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1); 
            //return View(airteldetails.ToList());
            return View(airteldetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
      }
```

View

```
   <h2 style="text-align:center">AirtelDetails</h2>
       @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewDataOfDatabase", "AirtelManagement",FormMethod.Post))
{
<h3>Search by PhoneNumber:@Html.TextBox("SearchString",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)</h3>

    <p><h3>Year:@Html.DropDownList("Yearitems",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList, "Select Year")</h3>
    <h3>Month:@Html.DropDownList("MonthItems", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectMonthList, "Select Month")</h3>
    <h3>City: @Html.DropDownList("CityNames", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CityList, "Select City")</h3></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Yearitems").change(function () {
            //debugger;
            //alert($("#Yearitems>option:selected").attr("Value"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetMonths","AirtelManagement")',
                data: { YearId: $("#Yearitems>option:selected").attr("Value") },
                datatype: "Json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //debugger;
                    $("#MonthItems").html("");
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        $("#MonthItems").append(new Option(item.MonthName, item.MonthSelectedId));
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Select Year");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

}
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ViewDataOfDatabase", "AirtelManagement", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Comment: @EhsanSajjad check it out.. i've added code now

Comment: Please try creating a view model class to reduce the complexity and try using collection in this viewmodels to bind to dropdowns and allow mvc modelbinder to give you the viewmodel back than using these large number of params in actionmethod

Comment: @linodh please can elaborate little more about binding..

Comment: `code`public class SomeViewModel {
public List<SelectListItem> CityList{get; set;} public int City{get;set;}
***add other properties: year,currentFilter, sort order etc****
} in view use : @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.City, Model.CityList, "Select City" )

Comment: @linodh I've tried but its not working..